# DOMException when calling getUserMedia using React

Tags: reactjs, getusermedia

I am building a web application for mobile. I am trying to access the camera using getUserMedia in google chrome.

My application is built in react and i am having issues when trying this, giving me the following error.

> Error:  DOMException

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "./LiveFace.scss";
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import faceimage from "./../../../images/face.png";
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { updateFace } from "./../actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';


export class LiveFace extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            progress: 0,
        }
    }


    continue = async (e) => {

    }

    componentDidMount = () => {

        const constraints = { video: { facingMode: 'user' } };

        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
                .then(this.handleSuccess.bind(this)).catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
        }

    }

    handleSuccess = (stream) => {

        console.log(this.refs);
        this.track = stream.getTracks()[0];
        this.refs.video.srcObject = stream;
        this.started = true;

    }

    handleError = (error) => {
        console.error('Error: ', error);
    }

    render() {
        const { handleChange } = this.props;
        return (
            <div id="live">
                <div className="videoContainer">
                        <video ref="video" autoPlay playsInline muted></video>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className="live-footer">

                        <Button className="live-button" type="submit" variant="contained" onClick={this.start} color="primary">
                                Start Live Face Capture
                        </Button>
                        <br />
                    <LinearProgress variant="determinate" className="progress-bar" value={this.state.progress} />

                    </div>

                <canvas ref="canvas" className="screenshotCanvas"></canvas>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {updateFace})(LiveFace);
```

I request permission when the component is mounted it fails on this line `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)` and then throws an error which triggers `handleError()` function and the console log is what you can see in the above error quote.

Its not giving any more details, can someone tell me what is happening here?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted
go to this link , it may help

Comment: @KishanJaiswal im not calling video.play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: DOMException

this error comes in some case like, you have not connected the camera with the System or driver are not installed in your system.

another case it would require a secure connection.

Comment: Even on my laptop it is not working which has a camera

Comment: than you tried by allow the site permission allow camera just like we allow microphone for website to record

Comment: Ye i can see in chrome the setting is set to Allow, there are 2 other options block and  ask. So my browser is defiantly allowed it.

Comment: if on local that doesn't work you can create a small demo and create a build and host on now server , NOW provide you a easy way to host and give you a https secure connection and gives you a url https://zeit.co/now

Comment: Im already hosting it on https connect and it doesen't work there either.

Comment: This should work using localhost, because i have a html only page (no react) that is working.

Comment: can you call a function on a button click and than  check by palcing this into the function `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)`

Comment: So in the end it turned out that my camera on mac laptop crashed. Chrome silently errors but firefox throws an actual telling me it can't find the device.

Comment: great to hear that we caught the problem you can upvote it if you feel its helps you ,